# AngularJS: Infinite scroll w/ <table>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I have infinite scroll working w/ one set of data properly.  When I'm doing a similar task (image index) using an HTML table, the loadMore() function is being called far too often. Generally one light scroll will go through the whole set of data. Google didn't give me a specific example using a table, so wondering if I'm messing something up.

```
    <table>
        <span infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance='2' infinite-scroll-disabled="load_disabled">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data">
            <td data-ng-repeat="item in row">
                <div class="image_box">
                    <img data-ng-src="{{item.thumb_src}}"><br>{{item.title_eng}}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </span>
    </table>
```

Javascript. Note that $scope.data is an array of arrays of my items.  $scope.data[0] will have 5 items, which hold a thumbnail, and a bit of text.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','infinite-scroll'])
.controller("imageController",
        ['$scope',
        '$http',
        '$routeParams',
        '$rootElement',
        '$location',
        function($scope,$http,$routeParams,$rootElement,$location) {


$scope.data = new Array();
row = -1;

for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {

    if ( i % 5 == 0  ) {
        row++;
        $scope.data[row] = new Array();
    }

    var item = [];
    item["title_eng"] = "title " + i;
    $scope.data[row].push( item );
}

console.log( "We got " + row + 1 + " rows." );

$scope.rows = new Array();
var row_ix = 0;

$scope.loadMore = function() {

    if ( !$scope.data[row_ix] || !$scope.data[row_ix].length ) {
        return;
    }

    var x = 1; // 1 at a time
    console.log( "row_ix:  " + row_ix + "." );
    for ( var i = 0; i < x; i++ ) {
        $scope.rows[row_ix] = new Array();
        $scope.rows[row_ix] = $scope.data[row_ix].slice(0);
        row_ix++;
    }
}

angular.module('infinite-scroll').value('THROTTLE_MILLISECONDS', 250);\
```

EDIT: Coming back to this after some time off.  The Throttle seems to not be working. :(

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: You can also set the infinite-scroll throttle constant in your application - see 'Throttling scroll events' @ http://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html

Comment: Lloyd: I will try but need to work some voodoo. :)   Mike: Thanks, but I never figured out how this may or may not help me in this case.  I've used the disable feature (to stop loading when there's no more data) but other than that I'm a bit lost. :)

Comment: Mike is saying to set the `THROTTLE_MILLISECONDS` constant which will only allow your `loadMore()` function to be called a maximum of once every x milliseconds

Comment: jsFiddle is killing me w/o a console.  Until I figure that out, you can see a quick & dirty of it here.  http://onfilm.us/gamengai/ix2.html?sys=10

First issue: initial load only draws 1 row.  2nd issue is that it's called far too often.

Comment: @Ronnie, gotcha. I thought it was the infinite-scroll-disabled bit. My fault.  Where exactly would I set that?  The doc says I might call XXX after the module has been initialized. (Note: Your comment didn't show up until a bit later as I had the edit window open).

Comment: You put `angular.module('infinite-scroll').value('THROTTLE_MILLISECONDS', 250)` after `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);` You won't have `myApp` but the rest should be the same (you included `['infinite-scroll']` somewhere)

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried that (and still have it there) all within the same script tag, but nothing has changed.  I looked around in the ng-infinite-scroll.js file to see if I could add a line of output to the console to ensure it was being set, but nothing seemed obvious.

Comment: can you post where you decalare you app and the line you have to set the constant?

Comment: Sure -- done.  Edited the original post.

Comment: that code doesn't look right. You are missing an ending `}` Are you using a developer console to see if there are any errors? Do you have a URL we can look at? The one you posted doesn't appear to be displaying anything,

Comment: This is the only link I have.  http://onfilm.us/gamengai/ix2.html  And yes, I'm using a console, which is how I see it calling loadMore() too often. No errors output there.  If you don't see the page outputting anything try to scroll... that might get it going.

Comment: did you have any joy & find a solution?